# How to build and install google-url as a shared library on Mac OS/Linux

Tags: c++, google-chrome, build, shared-libraries

I want to use [google-url](http://code.google.com/p/google-url/) in my project as a shared library on Linux\Mac OS, but can not figure out the right way to build it...

**Question:** what is the way you suggest to build it from scratch form official sources?
Requirements - be able to stay in sync with official repo and use standard(make) tools.

---

As far as i can see, right now there are few ways to build it:

- in the **official repo** itself only Visual Studio 2005 build files are included
- it is in use at **Chromium** and so [there is .gyp available](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/build/temp_gyp/googleurl.gyp) for it but looks like it is tight integrated with Chromium build structure, so there is no easy way to generate Makefile for the standalone library build.
  Although it has a comment inside "*TODO(mark): Upstream this file to googleurl.*"
  So at list this considered to be possible.
- Googleurl is also integrated with **PageSpeed project** in [.gyp](http://page-speed.googlecode.com/svn/lib/trunk/src/build/temp_gyp/googleurl.gyp) form (thought no the same one as above) and so it is somehow built there
- third-party **bindings for python** are available and also contain some [build instructions](http://code.google.com/p/python-google-url/wiki/HowToBuildGoogleUrlWithLinux), but with SCons this time, and AFAIK it is kind of obsolete system to rely on.

Looks like i'm not the only one with this trouble, so other people i found both just implemented their own build files using autotools:

- https://github.com/artemg/Googleurl-separate-library
- https://github.com/commoncrawl/commoncrawl-crawler/blob/master/src/native/src/libGoogleURL/googleurl/README.google

It could work but the filesystem layout is not the same as in official repo/they have local modification  so there are no easy way to downstream changes and stay in sync.

The most tempting way would be to use GYP to generate platform-specific build files for the oficial repo once: make/xcode/visual studio, then just save and use them later as needed..but i have no idea how to approach this and where to start from.